# Apollo Server: Eject built in "Upload" Type to generate TS Types with graphql-codegen

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am using `graphql-codegen` to generate my TS Types of my GraphQL TypeDef files. I also use the built in `Upload` Type from apollo server to handle file uploads but the Upload TypeDef is not in my own schema, its somewhere built into apollo-server itself. When I try to generate via the `graphql-codegen`, I receive an error:

```
Error: Unknown type "Upload". Did you mean "Float"?

Unknown type "Upload". Did you mean "Float"?
```

because its not in my own typedef files.

Can I somehow `eject` the builtin apollo "Upload" type to add the typedef by myself?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. You have to define your own Upload type, define a custom scalar in your `codegen.yml` config file, and some other things.

```yaml
# codegen.yml
config:
  scalars:
    Date: Date
    Upload: FileUpload
```

You can import your custom FileUpload type in your generated files with the plugin add-content of graphql-codegen (`@graphql-codegen/add`):

```yaml
# codegen.yml
generates:
  # Schema ans resolvers types
  ./src/graphql/generated/schema.types.ts:
    plugins:
      - add:
          content: "import { FileUpload } from \"path/to/your/type/file\""
      - typescript
```

```
import { ReadStream } from "fs"

export interface FileUpload {
  filename: string
  mimetype: string
  encoding: string
  createReadStream(): ReadStream
}
```

BTW, you should install `@types/node`.
And, in order to make things simpler, you must define a scalar in your graphql schema (otherwise graphl-cogeden will tell you that `Upload` is unknown.

So:

```
# schema.graphql
scalar Upload
```

And, if you use Apollo Server 2, the default Apollo's behaviour is to automatically add `scalar Upload` in your schema, so you need to use the `makeExecutableSchema` from, `graphql-tools`!

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
  })
```

Enjoy!